# get_terms problem : related articles

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to use get_the_term_list to catch the name of the current taxonomy of the page, and then use it with get_terms and a foreach method, to show the result of all the "elements" from the same taxonomy, but i only got an empty result. (for example, this is to have the related articles of the page).

Do you know why it doesn't work? The echo on get_the_term_list works ok, but then in the parameter of get_terms, the result of the "li"s is blank.

```
$my_tax = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'type');
//echo $my_tax;?> output works fine

$terms = get_terms($my_tax);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
echo "<li>".$term->name."</li>"; // empty
}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_term_list()` is retrieving the terms attached to the post that are in the taxonomy "types".

`get_terms()` is designed to retrieve all the terms within a taxonomy.

What you are trying to do is use `get_terms()` for a specific term in a taxonomy, not a taxonomy itself.

You need to do: `$terms = get_terms('type');`

Comment: @kaiser : thanks - but what if i don't want to write the 'type' of the page myself, and if i want it to automatically know the 'term', and THEN find the other elements into this precise term? would it be possible? otherwise i'll need to write each time the 'type', which is not really practical...

Comment: You can use get_taxonomies() to store the taxonomy object in a variable http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies and then do `get_terms()` on the taxonomy name.

Comment: @Pippin: I'm not the author of this A. I just edited the code formatting when reading the Q & A.

Comment: @Pippin : Thanks, i don't find how to reach "the taxonomy of the current post" ? Do the parameters in get taxonomy allow it?

Comment: You have to know the name of the taxonomy that is on the post. As long as you know the name, you can do: `get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'tax_name');`

Comment: @Pippin : thanks, i thought it would be possible to do it dynamically, but if it's not... i'll change on my own every page, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_taxonomies( $post->ID )` allows you to dynamically retrieve the names of the taxonomies attached to a post.

So you could retrieve ALL of the terms that belong to the current post's taxonomies:

```
$all_terms = get_terms( get_post_taxonomies( $post->ID ) );
```

OR just the terms that are assigned to the current post:

```
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, get_post_taxonomies( $post->ID ) );
```

I'll take it a step further and implement get_the_term_list() for each taxonomy:

```
foreach( get_post_taxonomies( $post->ID ) as $taxonomy ) {
    $taxonomy_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->name;
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $taxonomy, '<h3>' . $taxonomy_name . '</h3><ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
}
```